# Visual Studio add-in for WSF and WSC files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, scripting, wsh, wsc

Are there any add-ins for Visual Studio that assist with editing WSF and WSC files?

WSF and WSC (Windows Script Component) files are XML files that are interpreted by the WIndows Script Host.  They contain script metadata in XML elements, and one or more scripts in CDATA blocks.

Sapien PrimalScript does a great job of handling these files, and displays them as a "workspace" (or a "Solution" in VS parlance) with the embedded scripts shown, and editable, separately with syntax highlighting, basic intellisense, etc.

When I open these files in VS it just displays as an XML file.

Is there an add-in for Visual Studio that will do more like what PrimalScript does?  I can use PrimalScript if I have to, but I'd rather not install a separate tool if I can help it.

Comment: What kind of files are these?

Comment: @John Saunders: I just added a description of the files to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this comment](http://mjjames.blogspot.com/2009/01/syntax-highlighting-and-intellisense.html?showComment=1277653713237#c1376977537118625745), I added WSC as a file extension in VS2010 > Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension, and set the editor to be HTML Editor.

This allowed me to have Intellisense working for anything in the CDATA section of my WSC file.

Comment: In VS2017 the Editor now needs to be set to "Windows Scripting Host File Editor" for the WSC extension.